# Chrome app can't be maximized

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I know that there is a maximize function but my boss wants to be able to click the little green button on his yosemite mac.

This was working at one point but now the little green button is disabled.

[image]

I am playing with the window sizes like this:

```
service.setChromeToMinSize = function(){
  var monitorWidth = window.screen.availWidth;
  var monitorHeight = window.screen.availHeight;
  var top = Math.round((monitorHeight / 2) - (568 / 2));
  var left = Math.round((monitorWidth / 2) - (400 / 2));

  chrome.app.window.current().innerBounds.maxWidth = 400;
  chrome.app.window.current().innerBounds.maxHeight = 568;
  chrome.app.window.current().innerBounds.minWidth = 400;
  chrome.app.window.current().innerBounds.minHeight = 568;
  chrome.app.window.current().innerBounds.top = top;
  chrome.app.window.current().innerBounds.left = left;
  chrome.app.window.current().innerBounds.width = 400;
  chrome.app.window.current().innerBounds.height = 568;
};

service.setChromeToVideoSize = function(){

  var monitorWidth = window.screen.availWidth;
  var monitorHeight = window.screen.availHeight;
  var videoWidth = Math.round(monitorWidth/2);
  var videoHeight = Math.round(videoWidth * 9 / 16);
  var top = Math.round((monitorHeight / 2) - (videoHeight / 2));
  var left = Math.round((monitorWidth / 2) - (videoWidth / 2));

  chrome.app.window.current().innerBounds.maxWidth = 10000;
  chrome.app.window.current().innerBounds.maxHeight = 10000;
  chrome.app.window.current().innerBounds.minWidth = 1;
  chrome.app.window.current().innerBounds.minHeight = 1;
  chrome.app.window.current().innerBounds.top = top;
  chrome.app.window.current().innerBounds.left = left;
  chrome.app.window.current().innerBounds.width = videoWidth;
  chrome.app.window.current().innerBounds.height = videoHeight;
};
```

But even with all that commented, I get the same problem.

I start the app like this:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function(launchData) {
 chrome.app.window.create(
   'index.html',
{
  id: 'mainWindow',
  bounds: {width: 400, height: 568},
  minWidth: 400,
  minHeight: 568,
  maxWidth: 400,
  maxHeight: 568
    }
  );
});
```

**QUESTION:**
**How can I enable the little green button?**

Comment: ..just a guess, but what happens, if you set the `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` in `create` methods options object to `null`?

Comment: That almost worked. What did it in the end was for me to leave the ones in the background.js file and change the 10000 to null in my method. Aparantly a large number is not as good as null. Answer this with the details and I'll mark it as correct @jukempff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you have to set the innerBounds `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` to `null`, instead of a large number.

From [the bounds type documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#type-Bounds):

> A value of null indicates 'unspecified'.

Although the resulting limitation on fullscreen mode is not mentioned, it somehow makes sense to disable fullscreen mode with maxWidth/Height being set.